# REGEX working in chrome but breaks in safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, vue.js

The following javascript regex breaks in safari getting SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

```
/^(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9\'\.\-\,\s]*(?<!\s)$/.test('ABCD@#');
```

Can someone please help me to re write the regex which can work in safari?

I find out that safari doesn't support lookbehind but still not able to re write the whole regex which can be good for safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your pattern to avoid the negative lookbehind.  Since you seem to want a non whitespace character as the last character, just use a character class for that.

```
/^(?!\s)[A-Za-z0-9'.,\s-]*[A-Za-z0-9'.,-]$/.test('ABCD@#')
```

Side note: your current pattern looks wrong for what you are trying to match.